# Записать в первый байт строки количество элементов (символов) этой строки

Tags: c++

По заданию у меня строка ограничена длиной 254. В первый байт строки нужно вписывать количество элементов введенной строки, при этом сдвинуть уже записанную информацию.

Я реализовал это так:

```
int n = strlen(s);
char *s2;
char ch=n+'0';
s2 = new char [256]; // 254 +1 байт на первый символ и +1 байт на нуль-терминатор
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   s2[i]=s[i];
}
s[0]=ch;
for(int i=1; i<=n+1; i++)
{
   s[i]=s2[i-1];
   cout<<s[i-1];
}
```

Проблема в том, что строка у меня рассчитана на 254 символа, а с таким кодом я могу нормально реализовать только 9, потому что двузначные числа не могут записаться в один байт. Не знаю, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Какая строка ограничена 254 символами, входная или выходная? В последнем случае вы уже нарушаете условие т.к. с учетом добавленного символа их становится 255. Еще вопрос: зачем вы делаете это `char ch=n+'0';`? Сохраняйте в ch просто значение n, только убедитесь, что оно туда помещается. Это и будет решением вышей задачи. При выводе на экран,  для нулевого элемента массива, делайте обратное преобразование char то int.

Comment: Кстати , если у вас строка будет длинной более 207 символов, вы стройкой `char ch=n+'0'` превысите максимальное значение, которое помещается в char.

Comment: *двузначные числа не могут записаться в один байт* - в один байт могут записаться числа от 0 до 255.

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне с этими строками дальше ещё необходимо работать. И даже если я при одном выводе преобразую нулевой элемент, то все остальные функции со строками используют неизвестный символ. То же происходит, если я не использую char ch=n+'0', но проблема этого преобразования в том, что оно нормально работает только с числами до 9. В остальных случаях, когда количество символов больше 10, оно начинает выводить прочие символы, типа ; : и т.д.

Comment: А ведущий элемент не надо выводить, так как в нем содержится длина.

Comment: Я не знаю какую конкретно задачу вы решаете, но при дальнейшей работе со строками, вам в любом случае нужно учитывать, что в 0-ом элементе лежит длина строки, а сама строка начинается с 1-го. Т.е. вам все методы работы со строками нужно доработать с учетом этого факта. А то, что при подходе `char ch=n+'0',` выводятся символы отличные от цифр -  вполне ожидаемо. Почитайте про таблицу ASCII, разберитесь с типами данных и разберитесь когда и какой из них нужно использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, в первый байт вносить длину только строки, строки с учетом первого байта, или как? Вот, если считать только байты в строке, без нулевого и первого с длиной.

```
int n = strlen(s);
assert(n >= 0 && n <= 254);
s2 = new char [256];
*(unsigned char*)s2 = n;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
   s2[i+1] = s[i];
}
```

Собственно, это все.